# how to personalise Json Output for a list of Pandas DataFrame and other output datas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following code, which gives the information

1. Salary received per month and balance before the salary been credited
2. check whether salary is been credited before 5th of every month, if yes then list of salary with date.
3. average salary of last 3 months

**Code**

```
    if Salary.empty:
        total_Salary = 0
        Salary_b4_5th = "No"
        #sum_Salary = {'Salary': "-",'date': "-"}
        avg_Salary_3months = 0
        print("--------------")
        print("Is salary received before 5th :", Salary_b4_5th)
        print("--------------")
        print("No of times salary received :", total_Salary)

    else:

        Salary.date = pd.to_datetime(Salary.date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
        check_Salary_date = Salary[Salary['date'].dt.day <= 5].groupby('date').sum()
        check_Salary_date.index = check_Salary_date.index.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
        check_Salary_date.index.name = 'Date'
        sum_Salary = Salary.groupby('date').sum()
        sum_Salary = Salary.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()
        sum_Salary_3months = Salary.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).mean().dropna(subset=['Salary']).tail(3)
        avg_Salary_3months = sum_Salary_3months['Salary'].mean()
        sum_Salary.index = sum_Salary.index.strftime('%b-%y')
        sum_Salary.index.name = 'Month'
        total_Salary = len(sum_Salary.axes[0])
        print("--------------")
        print("\nSalary received per month \n", sum_Salary)
        print("--------------")
        print("Total Count of salary received :", total_Salary)
        print("--------------")
        if not check_Salary_date.empty:
            Salary_b4_5th = "Yes"
            print("\nIs salary credited before 5th of every month:", Salary_b4_5th)
            print("--------------")
            print("List of salary credited before 5th : \n", check_Salary_date)
        else:
            Salary_b4_5th = "No"
            print("\nIs salary credited before 5th of every month:", Salary_b4_5th)
        print("--------------")
        print("Avg Salary of last 3 months :", avg_Salary_3months)
        print("--------------")
```

**Output**

```
Is salary credited before 5th: True
List of date where salary received before 5th :
           Balance before Salary   Salary
Date
03-Aug-18                 176.48  14783.0
04-Sep-18                  48.48  16249.0
05-Oct-18                 241.48  14448.0

Salary received per month
        Balance before Salary   Salary
Date
Jun-18                  27.20  15300.0
Jul-18                  88.20  15300.0
Aug-18                 176.48  14783.0
Sep-18                  48.48  16249.0
Oct-18                 241.48  14448.0
Nov-18                  49.48  15663.0
--------------
Avg Salary of last 3 months : 15453.333333333334
--------------
```

Expected Json Output:

```
[{"Is salary credited before 5th": "True"},

{
    "List of salary credited before 5th": {
        "Balance before Salary": {
          "03-Aug-18":176.48,
          "04-Sep-18":48.48,
          "05-Oct-18":241.48

        },
        "Salary": {
        "03-Aug-18":14783.0,
        "04-Sep-18":16249.0,
        "05-Oct-18":14448.0

        }
    }
},
{
    "Salary received per month": {
        "Balance before Salary": {
          "Jun-18":27.2,
          "Jul-18":88.2,
          "Aug-18":176.48,
          "Sep-18":48.48,
          "Oct-18":241.48,
          "Nov-18":49.48

        },
        "Salary": {
          "Jun-18":15300.0,
          "Jul-18":15300.0,
          "Aug-18":14783.0,
          "Sep-18":16249.0,
          "Oct-18":14448.0,
          "Nov-18":15663.0}
    }
},

{"Avg Salary of last 3 months" : 15453.333333333334} 
]
```

**Questions:**

1. how will I save multiple DataFrames as a Json file.
2. how will I save multiple Non-DataFrames along with dataframes as a json file.

In short I want to get an output exactly as given in the **expected Json Output**. How to get this output?

Comment: How does `True` converted into `yes` in your first element of your expected output!

Comment: Sorry, It's `True` only. I have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_dict()`:

```
import json
expected_ans_1 = True
expected_ans_2 = 15453.333333333334

js = [{"Is salary credited before 5th": str(expected_ans_1)},
 {"List of salary credited before 5th": df1.to_dict()},
 {"Salary received per month": df2.to_dict()},
 {"Avg Salary of last 3 months": expected_ans_2}]

with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(js, outfile)
```

Store the user answers into variables `expected_ans_1` and `expected_ans_2`.
Here, `df1` and `df2` are your two dataframes.

Comment: How will I fit this into this model : `df.to_json("/path/test.json)` 
Where will I serialise this data ?

Comment: How do we create this format

`[{"Is salary credited before 5th": str(expected_ans_1)},
 {"List of salary credited before 5th": df1.to_dict()},
 {"Salary received per month": df2.to_dict()},
 {"Avg Salary of last 3 months": expected_ans_2}]`

Comment: can you please show me how to create that format? and how to save it as a json file in my local system

Comment: I've updated the answer as per your needs to save into json file. Creating that format requires list of nested dictionary as described.

Comment: I need your help, I got an error when the dataframes `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` was empty. so is there any way I can solve this

Comment: Before you pass df1 and df2 to to_dict, make sure to check length of both dataframes. Say if length is 0 then don't perform this operation. I hope you get it.

Comment: no, I did not .. I'm new to programming, so are you asking me to check with an if statement before to perform this operation?

Comment: I'm away from laptop. Will give solution once I get back.

Comment: @vrindabv I just checked, you will not get error due to empty dataframe. For example, make an empty dataframe and convert it a dictionary like `df = pd.DataFrame().to_dict()`  next, now print `df` .You'll observe that there appears no error rather an output of empty dictionary `{}` So the reason of error is something different which I can't state from limited provided data and info.

Comment: I have edited My question (code), you can see that if `salary` dataframe is empty then there wont be any `df1` or `df2` left so I get a error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185556/discussion-between-vrinda-bv-and-mew).